# Changing Screen Resolution in OSX Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, resolution

Screen of my MacBook Pro Retina 2015 is broken and a vertical block with ~2 inches width on the right edge can't be seen. I have been using it like this for a couple months since it is my second laptop. I want to change my screen resolution so that I can have a better experience.

ps. I don't mind changing to a linux distro but not windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Have you tried going to System Preferences → Displays → Display and selected Scaled under Resolution?

Comment: Yes but this is a pretty custom scale. I want to resize my screen so that it doesn't use the right 2" at all.

Comment: I don't think that can be done, in macOS or Windows. Your issue is likely hardware and I don't believe there is a way to tell the display software to not use the right 2" of any display.

Comment: I can use a vm with desired window size but I can't find any other workaround

Comment: Your MBP has a hardware problem. Fix it. Nothing can be done in software to remediate the problem. One option is to connect an external monitor. This may be less expensive than repairing the MBP, but it makes the laptop a desktop for all practical purposes.

Comment: @IconDaemon great tip yeah